# Selenium ExecuteScript

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a macro written earlier that works with an IE browser, where JS (Angular) code is executed like this:

```vb
oie.document.parentWindow.execScript "angular.element('[data-ng-click=""clickButton""]').triggerHandler('click');"
```

But now I rewrite the macro for work through the Chrome browser using Selenium ChromeDriver and when I try to execute the JS (Angular) code as well, the macro gives an error:

```vb
driver.ExecuteScript ("angular.element('[data-ng-click=""clickButton()""]').trigger('click');")
```

Help me please. How can I execute this code?

Comment: what error ? and is there an url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An  url would help but in the meantime you may try this re-write

```
driver.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('[data-ng-click=""clickButton()""]').click();"
```