# Click using ExecuteScript in selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to use ExecuteScript to click on a button instead of using `.Click` method but I got an error that tells me `Object doesn't support this property or method`

```
Dim eleSubmit As Selenium.WebElement
Set eleSubmit = .FindElementById("cmdSubmit")
        .ExcuteScript "arguments[0].click();", eleSubmit
```

I have found a solution using this line

```
.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('[id=""cmdSubmit""]').click();"
```

The web page doesn't load sometimes and that's weird. I thought the Click method is the cause (the page is loaded sometimes correctly but sometimes I got blank content)
This is my code

```
Private bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
    Set bot = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    With bot
        '.AddArgument ("--incognito")
        .Start
        .Get "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp"
        With .FindElementById("txtCaseNo")
            .Clear: .SendKeys "200078540"
        End With
        With .FindElementById("txtCaptcha2")
            .Clear: .Click
        End With
        
        .Wait 5000
        'Waiting for entering the captcha
        '.FindElementById("cmdSubmit").Click
        Dim eleSubmit As Selenium.WebElement
        Set eleSubmit = .FindElementById("cmdSubmit")
        '.ExcuteScript "arguments[0].click();", eleSubmit
        .ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('[id=""cmdSubmit""]').click();"
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr I have solved the first part of using ExecuteScript to click based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316388/